# XML xpath, get the child of root element

Tags: java, xml, xpath, docx4j

Below XML is provided for example.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <store d:mi="22">
           <book price="12.99" d:price="Number" d:mi="4">
                  <title d:constr="String" d:mi="1">Sword of Honour</title>
                  <category d:constr="String" d:mi="2">fiction</category>
                  <author d:constr="String" d:mi="3">Evelyn Waugh</author>
           </book>
           <book price="8.99" d:price="Number" d:mi="9">
               <sublist>
                  <title d:constr="String" d:mi="5">Moby Dick</title>
                  <category d:constr="String" d:mi="6">fiction</category>
                  <author d:constr="String" d:mi="7">Herman Melville</author>
                  <isbn d:constr="String" d:mi="8">0-553-21311-3</isbn>
               </sublist>
           </book>
           <Note price="8.95" d:price="Number" d:mi="13">
                  <title d:constr="String" d:mi="10">50</title>
                  <category d:constr="String" d:mi="11">reference</category>
                  <author d:constr="String" d:mi="12">Nigel Rees</author>
           </Note>
           <Note price="22.99" d:price="Number" d:mi="18">
                  <title d:constr="String" d:mi="14">The Lord of the Rings</title>
                  <category d:constr="String" d:mi="15">fiction</category>
                  <author d:constr="String" d:mi="16">J. R. R. Tolkien</author>
                  <isbn d:constr="String" d:mi="17">0-395-19395-8</isbn>
           </Note>
      </store>
```

Using the below Xpath I'm able to get the store element.

```
   String name = "String";
   String xpath = "//title[@d:constr='" + name + "']/parent::store";
```

But we need to get book(Anything may come which we Don't know) which is the child of store(constant word). Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below expression to match parent of required `title` ignoring node name:

```
String name = "String";
String xpath = "//title[@d:constr='" + name + "']/parent::*";
```

Also note that `store` is not parent of `title`, you should use `"//title/ancestor::store"` instead of `"//title/parent::store"`

If you simply want to get child of `store`:

```
//store/child::*
```

First child:

```
//store/child::*[1]
```